# AsyncImage does not download any images

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use AsyncImage do display some pictures, but it doesn't work at all. On my project, I have 2 environments, one with ssl, and one without ssl. On the "no-ssl" one is working. Also I tried in the playground and no images is displayed. Any help would be appreciated. I did debug it and I'm receiving this error : " A server with the specified hostname could not be found. "

This is the code :

```
public struct ImageView: View {
    private let image: Image?
    private let url: String?
    public init(image: Image? = Image("LandingTopImage"), url: String? = nil) {
        self.image = image
        self.url = url
    }

    public var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url ?? ""), content: { downloadedImage in
                downloadedImage
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }, placeholder: {
                image?
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .placeholder(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `URL(string: "")` is pointless. Better validate the URL string or pass a non-optional already validated `URL`.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me that `AsyncImage` does a simple `GET`, with no extra info to manage (like specific headers, auth etc.). So you might need to use a custom method for that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I didn't have the website's domain in "allowedDomains". I needed to add the domain of the website, now it works. :)